# SharePoint SpServices

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working on Sharepoint 2013 Autocomplete functionality

I created 2 lists

1) `FruitsList` --> List 1 |  FruitName --> column

2) `FruitFetching` --> List 2 |  Name of the fruit --> column

I gave the list of items to the `FruitsList` and what I want to achieve is I want to fetch the list of items from `Fruitfetching` list through Autocomplete.

I added the code in SharePoint webpart. Sharing the code below.

```
<link href= https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/autocomplete-0.3.0.css rel="stylesheet" />
<script src= https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.js type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src= https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.js type="text/javascript" ></script>    
<script src= https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js type="text/javascript" ></script>



<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    readyCall();    
});

function readyCall()
{
   var externalParties = [];
   $().SPServices({
   operation:"GetListItems",
   listName:"FruitsList",
   CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitName'/></ViewFields>",
    async:false,
   completrefunc:function(xData,Status){

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
    externaParties.push($(this).attr("FruitName"));
});
}

});

   $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
     source:externalParties});

}
</script>
```

This is my code. I added debugger  inside the function. but it is not going inside SPservices it is directly going to the input text box.

As I am new to SharePoint can anyone plz help on resolving this issue.

If I add an alert in the complete function I am geeting like this below screen shot
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As Call is async, you have to wait till servers returns fruitname, so you need to put initialization code inside your complete function. below is updated code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

readyCall();

});

function readyCall()
{
   var externalParties = [];
   $().SPServices({
   operation:"GetListItems",
   listName:"FruitsList",
   CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitName'/></ViewFields>",
    async:false,
   completefunc:function(xData,Status){

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
    externaParties.push($(this).attr("FruitName"));
});

 $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
     source:externalParties});

}

});



}
</script>
```

Comment: No it is not working. I am debugging the code it is not going to the second line of spservices

Comment: please correct spelling of complete function it is "completrefunc" it should be "completefunc"

Comment: Ya i corrected that one after that also it is not working

Comment: is the execution going inside completefunc ? what are you getting in Status variable ? try to put alert in alert(xData.responseXML.xml); to check the XML...paste screenshot of output of xml...

Comment: I put that alert in that complete function and i attached the screen shot

Comment: it seems you are not getting data from list, XML should not be undefined...hat are you getting in Status variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Tyr out below code and let me know if it works for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    readyCall();
});

function readyCall()
{
    var externalParties = [];
    $().SPServices({
        operation:"GetListItems",
        listName:"FruitsList",
        CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitName'/></ViewFields>",
        async:false,
        completrefunc:function(xData,Status){
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
                externalParties.push($(this).attr("ows_FruitName"));
            });
        }
    });

    $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
        source:externalParties});
}
</script>
```

Comment: No it is not working. I am debugging the code it is not going to the second line of spservices

Comment: just try to run the code without debugging.

Comment: No luck, its not working

Comment: are you seeing any error in console ?

Comment: No i am not seeing any error

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got a solution for the above question, I am sharing the details below

```
<link href= "https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/autocomplete-0.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src= "https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src= "https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src= "https://alshayacom.sharepoint.com/sites/TimesheetDEV/MasterDetailSite/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>




<script  language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

readyCall();

});

function readyCall()
{

   document.getElementById('Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField').title = 'FruitNames';

  $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
              sourceList: "FruitsList",
            sourceColumn: "FruitNames",
            columnName: "FruitNames",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 50,
            debug: true


});



}
</script>
```