# I am trying to achieve autosuggestion functionality using jquery for SharePoint but not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, spservices

I am trying to achieve autosuggestion functionality using jquery for SharePoint but my code does not go fire the `operation: getlistitem` it directly jumps from there and goes to the input code

```
<script language ="javascript"  type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

readyCall();

});

function readyCall()
{
   var externalParties = [];

  debugger;
   $().SPServices({
   operation:"GetListItems",
   listName:"FruitsList",
   CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitNames'/></ViewFields>",
    async:false,
   completrefunc:function(xData,Status){   
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
    externaParties.push($(this).attr("ows_FruitNames"));
});
}

});

   $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
     source:externalParties});

}
</script>
```

Comment: Which version do you have of SharePoint?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicate to [SharePoint SpServices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200353/sharepoint-spservices/200355)

As Call is async, you have to wait till servers returns fruitname, so you need to put initialization code inside your complete function. below is updated code.

Also correct your spelling mistake of "completrefunc" to "completefunc"
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
readyCall();

});

function readyCall()
{
   var externalParties = [];
   $().SPServices({
   operation:"GetListItems",
   listName:"FruitsList",
   CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitName'/></ViewFields>",
    async:false,
   completefunc:function(xData,Status){

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
    externaParties.push($(this).attr("FruitName"));
});

 $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
     source:externalParties});

}

});



}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is uses async way to execute the methods so its behaving like that i guess.

modify your code like below it may work

```
<script language ="javascript"  type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

readyCall();

});

function readyCall()
{
   var externalParties = [];

  debugger;
   $().SPServices({
   operation:"GetListItems",
   listName:"FruitsList",
   CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FruitNames'/></ViewFields>",
    async:false,
   completrefunc:function(xData,Status){   
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
    externaParties.push($(this).attr("ows_FruitNames"));    
    });

     $("input[id$='Name_x0020_Of_x0020_the_x0020_Fr_5df8c07d-1dd7-4e65-a9fe-695dbe65f187_$TextField']").autocomplete({
     source:externalParties});

}

});

}
</script>
```